# How to read a content of a file and ignore the value after a comma on PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file containing the sample below

```
sample.txt
server1
server2
server3,servename
```

I would like to read the text file and return everything except the values after a comma if it has one
I am currently using the code below to read and return the content but I am not sure how to strip the value after a comma

```
$ServerList = Get-Content sample.txt
$ServerList
```

Expected result:

```
server1
server2
server3
```

I will be needing the $ServerList array so calling and using split on the values one by one will not work.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Using:ServerList -ScriptBlock { some code here }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution to just read $ServerList and then pass the values unto a new array while using Split.

```
    $NewServerArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    $ServerList = Get-Content sample.txt
    ForEach ($Server in $ServerList)
    {
        $NewServerArray += $Server.Split(',')[0]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-Split` on the comma and then pull the first element from the array that is created:

```
$content = Get-Content $file 
$splitOperation= $content -Split ',' 
Write-Host $splitOperation[0]
```

Output will be:

> server1
>
> server2
>
> server3

Comment: I will need the actual array $ServerList later on in my code and calling the values one by one will not work.

Comment: @Ruben_PH $ServerList/$content is still available in my example. What do you mean "Calling the values one by one will not work"? If there are other points to this question please update it so that we can offer the best advice :)